# Implement VB With statement in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

How would you create an extension method which enables me to do the following (*warning: exteme pseudo-code*)...

```
class FooBar
{
    Int32 Foo { get; set; }
    String Bar { get; set; }
}

new FooBar().With(fb => new Func<FooBar, Object>(instance =>
{
    // VB With magic
    // NOTE: The instance parameter HAS to be by reference
    instance.Foo = 10;
    instance.Bar;

    return new Object();
}));
```

If you could specify anonymous functions without a return type (void), the above would look much cleaner...

```
new FooBar().With(fb => new Func<FooBar, void>(instance =>
{
    instance.Foo = 10;
    instance.Bar;
}));
```

This is pseudo-code of the worst kind. But I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
new FooBar().With( fb=> {
    fb.Foo = 10;
    fb.Bar = fb.Foo.ToString();
} );

// ... somewhere else ...
public static void With<T>( this T target, Action<T> action ) {
    action( target );
}
```

Comment: oh snap! you got there first.

Comment: So `fb` is by reference, and not by value, yes?

Comment: @roosteronacid - assuming `T` is a class then yes. If you want to enforce this put a constraint on the method `where T : class`. See answer below.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

To specify anonymous methods without return type, use `Action<T>` instead of `Func<T, TResult>`:

```
new FooBar().With(new Action<FooBar>(instance =>
{
    instance.Foo = 10;
    instance.Bar;
}));
```

(I don't quite see the point in this particular case, but I take your word on the pseudo code part...)

**Update**
Full example for being complete:

The extension method:

```
public static void With<T>(this T input, Action<T> action)
{
    action(input);
}
```

Sample usage

```
new FooBar().With(fb =>
{
    fb.Foo = 10;
    fb.Bar = "some string";
});
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly declare the `Action<FooBar>`, the compiler figures that out. Should you wish to, for clarity, the call would look like this:

```
new FooBar().With<FooBar>(new Action<FooBar>(fb =>
{
    fb.Foo = 10;
    fb.Bar = "some string";
}));
```

Comment: How would the extension method look like?

Answer (score 2):

As you asked how to write the extension, here goes

```
public static void With<T>(this T target, Action<T> action) where T : class
{
   action(target);
}
```

Personally dont see what benefit this has, but fill yer boots!

Answer (score 1):

How about just

```
return new FooBar{ Foo=10; };
```

Comment: Updated my question. I need the instance by reference.

Comment: To who ever did, it's a bit harsh to vote my answer down when it prompted an update in the question. It may not be relevant now with more information but at the time it was.